# Trying to graph $y = (2-z)^{1/2}$

Tags: vectors, graphing-functions, 3d

I tried to graph $y = (2-z)^{1/2}$ and I got half of a paraboloid that appears upside down from the point of $z = 2$ for $y$ values greater than or equal to $0$.

However, when I tried this on Geogobra, it did not work. I would like to know if it is because Geogobra does not support such an equation or if there is something fundamentally incorrect with the equation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just a guess: does Geogebra work if you write the equation as $y=(2-x)^{1/2}$?

Comment: @David, yes, it does

Comment: So, I don't really know anything about Geogebra, but maybe that's your answer: Geogebra expects equations for graphing to be in terms of $x$ and $y$.  Still just guessing though - any definite answers from experts?

Comment: @David thank you for your reply. So, the equation is fundamentally correct as I would be able to graph it by hand. Correct?